# unable to redirect with post body in java

Tags: java, redirect, post

so i have given a task to create a service that connects to a portal bank! i have to send user credit card information and the price to the bank portal ! and its all happens in back-end. meanwhile our company didnt used Spring MVC and so i cant use it also . i ve found a way to redirect without MVC but i cant make it a POST request with a body .
this is my code

```
@Path("/ag/v1")
public class RedirectTestClass {


@GET
@Path("/redirect")
public Response sourceSerivce(){
    URI uri = UriBuilder.fromUri("/ag/v1/bank").build();
    return Response.seeOther(uri).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).entity(new BankInfo("mmad", 1)).allow(HttpMethod.POST).build();
}


@POST
@Path("/bank")
public Response destinationBank(@RequestBody BankInfo test){
    return Response.ok(test.getTest()+"hoooray").build();
}

public static class BankInfo{
    public BankInfo(String test, int integer) {
        this.test = test;
        this.integer = integer;
    }

    @JsonProperty
    private String test;

    @JsonProperty
    private int integer;

    public String getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public void setTest(String test) {
        this.test = test;
    }

    public int getInteger() {
        return integer;
    }

    public void setInteger(int integer) {
        this.integer = integer;
    }
}
}
```

when i call the redirect serivce with postman i get 405 Method not Allow! how can i redirect it with POST method and body ?

PS: i know for external URL i need to add scheme to my response builder.

Comment: Where is your Test class that you use like `@RequestBody Test test`? Should it be `@RequestBody BankInfo test`?

Comment: @Ekrem my bad fixed it!